# How to get the value of a body tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

We know that we can get the value from a Form when the user enters some value in some input field, Is there anyway by which we can get the value from the whole body (if user type something on the body)? 
I tried adding `onkeyup="behavior()"` in the body tag of html page, and JavaScript behind that was

```
function behavior()
{
var key = document.body.value;
window.alert(key);
}
```

It didn't work, i also tried

```
var key = document.body.innerHTML;
```

Nothings working, how can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: How is your user able to write stuff on your `<body>`, what scenario?

Comment: @Roberrrt i meant when someone types on my webpage (anywhere).

Comment: Explore your `document.forms` collection for this.
`console.log(document.forms)`

Comment: *"It didn't work"* Can you elaborate on that? `body` doesn't have a `value` property. Only form control elements have that. Use `innerHTML` or `textContent`, depending on what you want.

Comment: _“i meant when someone types on my webpage (anywhere)”_ – just typing anywhere (outside of any form controls other other input elements) doesn’t change the content of body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a keyboard listening event.

```js
document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
  var keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode || e.charCode;
  var key = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += key;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head></head>
  <body>
    This is the body's content.
    <div id="output"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the `keyup` event on `window` object. This will basically catch every key typed on the webpage.

```js
window.onkeyup = function(e){
  //old browsers
  var keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode || e.charCode;
  var key = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);

  //modern browsers
  //var key = e.key;
  console.log(key);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to check which key is pressed..

```js
function keypressed(event) {
  console.log(event.which);
}
```

```html
<body onkeyup="keypressed(event);">


</body>
```

check console for ascii code of the keypressed.